# Will iPhone 5 and iPhone 4 getting obsolete now due to 64 bit architecture

Tags: ios, iphone

[image: My App build settings]

Apple in its latest releases throwing alerts like dropping of support for 32 bit apps, even speculations are going around the removal of apps from App Store which has 32 bit architecture app.

Does that mean iPhone 5, 5C and previous versions are getting shelved ?

Answer (score 0):

Apple introduced 64 bit support in iOS 7.  Apps built since then include both 64 bit and 32 bit versions.  Apps produced before then have only 32 bit code. 64bit devices could run these in an emulation mode.

iOS 11 no longer runs 32 bit only apps; This means that there are a number of apps that will no longer run when the device is upgraded to iOS 11.  I haven't seen any statement from Apple as to whether these apps will be removed from the App Store, maybe they will prevent them from being seen or downloaded by an iOS 11 device, just as an iOS 9 device can't install an app with a target of iOS 10+ today, or maybe they will be purged; we have already seen Apple purge a number of older apps from the store.

New binaries will continue to contain both 32bit and 64bit code, so as long they target a minimum iOS level that can run on the 32 bit devices, new/updated apps will continue to work.

Comment: So If we build an app with both 32bit and 64bit architectures, would we still get the message " Your Developer needs to improve the app compatibility"

Comment: no.  That message is only shown for 32-bit only apps

Comment: Please have a look at the image on the post, because for the app which was built through that configuration is throwing that pop up

Comment: You should have armv7s in that list as well.  I don't have a real device running iOS11, only a simulator but I don't get that warning, however if you are targeting iOS11 then there is no need for 32 bit code.  I released an app just yesterday with `arm64, armv7, armv7s` targeting iOS 10.3 and don't get that warning

Comment: I unzipped the ipa file and tried this command
lipo -info Payload/Test.app/Test

Architectures in the fat file : Payload/Test.app/Test are: armv7 arm64

But still i was able to get the message

Comment: What device are you getting the message on? What iOS is it running?  Since you are targeting ios11. What happens if you remove armv7?  What happens if you add amrv7s?

Comment: Let's say I want to reproduce the warning message how to do it ? Since the app throws warning message  only once in life time, even uninstall and install also doesn't work. I even tried complete reset of the device even that didn't work