# Will older apple (32 bit) devices get apps updates

Tags: ios, app-store, 32bit-64bit

As we know, with iOS 11, apple will drop support for 32 bit applications. 
This mean, that all application on new iOS need to be 64 bit.

I also understand, that (for some time now) developers need to upload 64 bit application on store.

My question is for older devices with 32 bit processor, that will stuck with older iOS (like 10.3), will that get apps updates?

My question is, when we developers upload 64 bit application, now on apple side is converted to 32 bit and can be run on 32 bit devices. Will this continue, or is apple removing all updates for 32 bit applications, and all old devices would stuck with old applications?

Comment: interesting question. But I don't think Apple would support for 32-bit devices like they did with iPhone 4s & 4 devices.

Comment: You can continue to upload 32/64 bit apps to support old devices as long as your app targets < iOS 11 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625715/will-iphone-5-and-iphone-4-getting-obsolete-now-due-to-64-bit-architecture/44626400#44626400